# How to get last month sale and this month sale in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table

How to get last month sale and this month sale in sql server 2008
Here my table structure is:

```
DailyDispatchID int Unchecked 
Name    varchar(50) Checked
Qty int Checked
Month   varchar(50) Checked
```

i tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Name,
               Gas,
               Qty,
               Month
        FROM   DailyDispatch) AS s
       PIVOT (Sum(QTY)
             FOR [month] IN(aug,
                            sep)) AS P
```

i am getting the output,but its taking only from August and September monthly only. it should generate automatically this month and previous sales. how to sort out this.,

Comment: Then you need to use current and previous month names in FOR condition.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the parameter in the in clause according  to your current month and last month

Comment: how to set the parameter and pass to rdlc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name,
       Gas,
       Qty,
       [Month]
FROM   DailyDispatch
WHERE  [Month] IN (SELECT CASE
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 1 THEN 'jan'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 2 THEN 'feb'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 3 THEN 'mar'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 4 THEN 'apr'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 5 THEN 'may'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 6 THEN 'jun'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 7 THEN 'jul'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 8 THEN 'aug'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 9 THEN 'sep'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 10 THEN 'oct'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 11 THEN 'nov'
                            WHEN Month(Getdate()) = 12 THEN 'dec'
                          END [month]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT CASE
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 1 THEN 'jan'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 2 THEN 'feb'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 3 THEN 'mar'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 4 THEN 'apr'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 5 THEN 'may'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 6 THEN 'jun'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 7 THEN 'jul'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 8 THEN 'aug'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 9 THEN 'sep'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 10 THEN 'oct'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 11 THEN 'nov'
                            WHEN Month(Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = 12 THEN 'dec'
                          END [month])
```

Comment: i have to display in the same column,whether we can use pivot in tihs table.

Comment: @Sarvan I was't able to paste my code here getting error like error occured submitting answer. can you create sqlfiddle

Comment: no how i can use in the report,i getting the select qery in the result.